# Resolving the 'WinMain@16' Link Error for Console

Tags: c, winapi, dll

I've been using the default template in Code::Blocks to create a DLL, but when I compile, I get the **undefined reference to'WinMain@16' error**.

I Googled out this error and it seems that the `main()` I'm using is for a Window application rather than console application but there's no clear solution to this problem.

Now, do I just replace this line

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
```

by this
int `main()`?

Also, I want to insist that whatever alternative causes the least security gap and/or is the most correct solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confused. First you say that you are building a DLL, but you later say that you are building an application. Which is it? (And if you're building a DLL, then the question of Windows vs console is meaningless, since console-ness is an attribute of applications, not DLLs.)

Comment: Excuse me @Raymond Chen, you are right, I want to build a DLL in Code::Blocks, that's it

Comment: If the linker is looking for `WinMain@16` then you did not configure your IDE correctly. You told it to build a GUI application, not a DLL. DLLs do not have a `main` since they are not an application. They are just a library. The main application has the `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter this same error sometime ago, just replacing some part of the code fixes it. I was using SDL in my program. This was the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

I relaced it with the windows main function:

```
int WinMain(int argc, char** argv)
```

but it did end up with giving a warning for the same however the code runs.